# How to use negation in helm-gid

Tags: helm

I would like to be able to execute `M-x helm-gid` and type in:

```
one two !three
```

But the "!" operator seems to be treated as if it is looking for id's that contain the "!" character. It works great in `helm-occur` and `helm-find-files`, but I can't see to get it to work in `helm-gid`.

Is this user error or simply something not implemented?

I'm using helm version 20190509.558 installed via the `list-packages` interface on Ubuntu 18.04.